# json_encode() value does not propagate right format

Tags: json, ajax, codeigniter

I am using json_encode function for getting value in ajax response.

```
$product_id = $this->input->get('product_id');
        if ($data = $this->sales_model->getProductById($product_id)) {
            //$product_id     = $data->id;
            $product_name   = $data->name;
            $product_unit   = $data->product_unit;
            $sales_price    = $data->sales_price;
            $product_details = array('product_id' => $product_id, 'product_name' => $product_name, 'product_unit' => $product_unit, 'sales_price' => $sales_price);
            //add the header here
            header('Content-Type: application/json');
            echo json_encode($product_details);
        }
```

Then in local server getting value as

```
Object {product_id: "77", product_name: "Testdescription", product_unit: "", sales_price: "120.00"}
```

But when I am uploading it into server then we are not getting any response.

the ajax calling function:

```
 $.ajax({
                type: "get",
                url: "index.php?module=sales&view=getproductinfo",
                dataType: "json",
                contentType:"application/json",
                data: {product_id: data_id},
                error: function() {
                    $('#info').html('sss');
                },
                success: function (response) {
                    console.log(response);
}
});
```

Comment: check your base_url first.

Comment: First check with your 'url' by doing console.log(url). Whether you getting proper url or not. It seems it not getting server url properly.

Comment: `url: "<?php echo base_url()?>/index.php?module=sales&view=getproductinfo",`

Answer (score 0):

maybee you can use ../index.php?module=sales&view=getproductinfo, and on error console.log(respon) to get your problem

Answer (score 0):

You have checked that data_id which you have sent in the prodict_id is passed correctly .If not passed then response will be blank with out any error.